# AWS S3 with Cloudfront returning strange response headers causing CORS issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am currently using aws s3 with cloudfront.

The data protection is done by signed cookie.

Now i encountered a very annoying problem which happened SOMETIMES,

but not always.

That is the response of the cloudfront is giving some strange response headers :

1. access-control-allow-methods of: GET PUT POST
2. access-control-allow-origin of: *

```js
accept-ranges: bytes
access-control-allow-methods: GET, PUT, POST
access-control-allow-origin: *
age: 13127
content-length: 523
content-type: application/x-mpegURL
date: Thu, 04 Jul 2019 14:59:42 GMT
etag: "xxxxxx416be945db1e53056"
last-modified: Mon, 01 Jul 2019 09:58:35 GMT
server: AmazonS3
status: 304
vary: Origin
via: 1.1 xxxx89f8fad65fe7a4.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-id: xxxxxtg6Ys3VBT8XOw9spA==
x-amz-cf-pop: xxx54-C1
x-cache: Hit from cloudfront
```

However, my CORS Policy setting in my S3 bucket only allows

1. GET + OPTION
2. example.com (which is my client side domain)

I have no idea how the above response comes up. 
And it happened sometimes and not always.
Please help!!

Comment: P.S. I am working with signed cookie and HLS streaming content. Therefore "withCredentials" are included in the request header. Don't know if this is related to the issue. (I guess it isn't~)

Comment: Can you please post your response as text in your question?

Comment: hi @party-ring , do you mean the response data? The data is retrieved successfully. So the signed cookie worked.